# Clearing all the textboxes on load

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a user control form. In that form, I can edit/update the content or I can insert the new things and save it.
Both the things work.

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <table id="manage-project">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="NameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    <table>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Now, the issue is when I want to insert something new, the data gets already bind and loads.

But, I want that if the page that has taken this user control, is insert, then all the texboxes should be empty, else it should bind the data.

I have a form with 20 textboxes.

Comment: `do a google search on the `Controls` class. specifically `forearch Control` you will find numerous examples on line as well .. and the number of TextBoxes doesn't matter when you are using a foreach loop.. also this can be done just as easy using a `linq/lambda`  expression.. by the way this will be done in the codebehind of the particular classes `.cs file`

Answer (score 0):

This is in vb.net and I don't have time right now to convert but it should be easy

```
 Dim x As Control
    For Each x In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf x Is TextBox Then
            x.ResetText()

        End If
```